# Creating a small add/subtract calculator with tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've for the most part created the program using the tkinter GUI tools, I just cannot see where I've gone wrong in the actual point where the + or - are clicked. It should be taking the value entered into the entry field, and adding it to the result label, but it's throwing a TypeError saying can only concatenate str (not "StringVar") to str.

```
import tkinter

class Calculator_GUI:

def __init__(self):
    self.mw = tkinter.Tk()
    self.mw.title("Calculator")
    
    self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.mw)
    self.mid_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.mw)
    self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.mw)
    
    self.prompt_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, text = "Total: ")
    self.num_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.mid_frame, width = 15)
    
    self.add_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = "+", width = 10, command = self.add)
    self.minus_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = "-", width = 10, command = self.subtract)
    self.reset_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = "Reset", width = 10, command = self.reset)
    self.result = tkinter.StringVar()
    self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, textvariable = self.result)
    
    self.prompt_label.pack(side = "left")
    self.num_entry.pack(side = "left")
    self.add_button.pack(side = "left")
    self.minus_button.pack(side = "left")
    self.reset_button.pack(side = "left")
    self.result_label.pack(side = "left")
    
    self.top_frame.pack()
    self.mid_frame.pack()
    self.bottom_frame.pack()
    
    tkinter.mainloop()
    
def add(self):
    self.result = float(self.num_entry.get() + self.result)
    
def subtract(self):
    self.result = float(self.result - self.num_entry.get())
    
def reset(self):
    self.result.set(0)
    
calc = Calculator_GUI()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set and convert correctly

```
import tkinter

class Calculator_GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mw = tkinter.Tk()
        self.mw.title("Calculator")
        
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.mw)
        self.mid_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.mw)
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.mw)
        
        self.prompt_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, text = "Total: ")
        self.num_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.mid_frame, width = 15)
        
        self.add_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = "+", width = 10, command = self.add)
        self.minus_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = "-", width = 10, command = self.subtract)
        self.reset_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = "Reset", width = 10, command = self.reset)
        self.result = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.result.set('0')
        self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, textvariable = self.result)
        
        self.prompt_label.pack(side = "left")
        self.num_entry.pack(side = "left")
        self.add_button.pack(side = "left")
        self.minus_button.pack(side = "left")
        self.reset_button.pack(side = "left")
        self.result_label.pack(side = "left")
        
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.mid_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()
        
        tkinter.mainloop()
        
    def add(self):
        self.result.set (str(float(self.num_entry.get()) + float(self.result.get())))
        
    def subtract(self):
        self.result.set (str(float(self.result.get()) - float(self.num_entry.get())))
        
    def reset(self):
        self.result.set('0')
    
calc = Calculator_GUI()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I see now where I was going wrong now with not converting them to floats and then back to strings. Can I just ask the importance of using the "get" function for both self.num_entry and self.result.get? Just so I actually have an understanding of why that works?

Answer (score 1):

Since `self.result` is a `StringVar`, you need to use `self.result.set(...)` to update its value.

Also you need to convert the strings returned by `.get()` to number before doing the addition and substraction.

```py
class Calculator_GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.num_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.mid_frame, width = 15)
        self.num_entry.insert(0, '0') # initialize to zero 
        ...

    def add(self):
        try:
            self.result.set(float(self.num_entry.get()) + float(self.result.get()))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

    def subtract(self):
        try:
            self.result.set(float(self.result.get()) - float(self.num_entry.get()))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.result` is of type StringVar and StringVar.get() returns type str, therefore this error makes sense. Moreover, due to the same fact, you need to use the setter method `set()` in order to set your result label.
I tried it real quick and it works so far with one problem: it concatinates the strings instead of adding their parsed values. You need to parse the str before adding them.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I've rectified part of the problem using set() instead of self.result = ____

As far as the adding the parsed values, I'm not quite sure what that means, any chance of a more basic explanation? I'm pretty new to all of this.

Comment: For the second part, if you try to do this `str(5) + str(3)` the +-operator will be used as concatination, which will result in 53 instead of the wanted 8. Therefore, both parameter need to be numeric in order for the +-operator to work as addition.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).